# Selecting k numbers out of N sorted numbers to a minimize a condition/Formula

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, permutations

A sorted list of $\mathbf N$ numbers is given.

$X_1$ $\le$ $X_2$ $\le$ $X_3$ $\le$ ....  $\le$ $X_N$

Select $\mathbf K$ Numbers -  $Y_1$ , $Y_2$ , $Y_3$ , ..... , $Y_K$  -  Such that the following value is minimised.

$$\sum_{1 \le i \lt j \le k} |(Y_i-Y_j)| $$ 
Let's call it FORMULA.

- **My Approach**

I Select them such that $Y_1$ $\le$ $Y_2$ $\le$ $Y_3$ $\le$ ..... $\le$ $Y_K$  . Now we need to minimize

$$\sum_{1 \le i \lt j \le k} (Y_i-Y_j) $$

- **REAL DOUBT**

I m only considering $\mathbf K\,consecutive$ elements(could start from any position).

So, is it possible  that the **left out cases(i.e K non-consecutive elements ) give a lower value**(for the formula above) than the cases i consider ?

- **Bonus Question**

To calculate the FORMULA for a particular case  $\;Y_1$ $\le$ $Y_2$ $\le$ $Y_3$ $\le$ ..... $\le$ $Y_K$

I create another list with 
   $Z_j$= $(Y_{j+1} - Y_j) $   ---> **Equation1**

FORMULA = $\sum_{i=1}^{(n-1)}i(k-i)Z_i$ ---> **Equation2**

**Is this Correct?**

---

- **EDIT 1**

In my opinion , If there are such instances, they would  consist of equal elements in the       original list with N numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Minimisation of a distance sum](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518880/minimisation-of-a-distance-sum)  covering the REAL DOUBT

Comment: The bonus question formula is not correct.  If all the gaps are the same size, it would be correct without the $(k-i)$ term

Comment: @RossMillikan could u give an exmaple where it fails?
For List Y -10,20,30,40 (K=4) formula gives 100 . which is correct i think.

Comment: I just realized you are double using $i$ in the expression for $Z_i$  As written, all the $Z_i$ are the same and in your example would be $50$.  Were you thinking it is $Z_j$ and the last is $Y_j$?

Comment: Your edit to Equation 1 has not solved the problem.  On the right side $j$ is a dummy variable, so the value does not depend on $j$.

Comment: Eq1---> $Z_1$=$Y_2$-$Y_1$, $Z_2$=$Y_3$-$Y_2$,$Z_3$=$Y_4$-$Y_3$ ,......$Z_{k-1}$=$Y_k$-$Y_{k-1}$

Eq2----> Formula = 1(k-1)$Z_1$ +2(k-2)$Z_2$+...+(k-1)1$Z_k$
$@RossMillikan$ what say?

Comment: Then you should not have the sum in front.  Then the $Z$'s are $30,10,10$ and your last equation would be $1\cdot 3\cdot  30+2\cdot 2\cdot 10+1\cdot 3 \cdot 10=190$ vs $30+40+50+10+20+10=180$

Comment: why is   $Z_1$ = 30 ? since $Y_2$-$Y_1$ = 20 - 10 =10; 

@RossMillikan

Comment: Sorry for equation1 error! haven't slept in years! EDITED .
@RossMillikan Is it okay now? :D .. BTW thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, that is fine